# Auto-renewing itunes subscriptions - Sandbox limitations

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, in-app-subscription

I am implementing auto renewing subscriptions for the first time, and as part of this I want to cover all possible scenarios and handle all possible receipt fields.

However there seems to be a couple fields I can't seem to simulate. These are:

- price_consent_status
- cancellation_reason & cancellation_date

Price Consent Status

I can't seem to work out how to change the price of a subscription. I can add an introductory price, but not add a price change. Maybe this is due to the current In-App Purchase not being sent for review, so it's still in an editable status?

**Is there a way to test this in sandbox, without submitting everything?**

Cancellations

I don't believe sandbox users can access the management area of iTunes in order to cancel a subscription. Therefore cannot cancel a subscription in order to make this information available in iTunes validation response.

Even worse the Apple docs don't seem to give an example response or any indication of where the JSON keys are found (it reads as if it's a flat JSON structure, which is obviously not true).

*Note: I know the sandbox accounts auto-cancel. However they do not put the `cancellation_` keys in the receipt. So yes we can handle cancellations via the expiry but I'd like to be able to see all potential production values.*

**Does someone have an example receipt JSON that they can show me which includes this information?**

*Receipt field spec: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html*